# leaflet js map not updating marker and circle point to new location upon search on map

Tags: javascript, html, api, location

On default location it displays marker and circle point but When I search new location it doesn't update location, marker and circle point. It should update location, marker and circle to new searched location e.g. if search for "London" it should update location from previous, marker and circle should also be there on location of London.

[See problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPmBA.png)

```
<div class="container-fluid d-flex flex-column align-items-center area">
        <div class="search-area">
            <input type="text" placeholder="City" id="search">
            <button id="clickme" type="button">Search</button>
        </div>

    <div id="map"></div>
</div>



clickme.addEventListener("click",my=(e)=>{
          e.preventDefault();
          var city=search.value;
          fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&appid=ac3673a8887645fc3d0493904a348e03`)
          .then(response=> response.json())
          .then(data=>{
              var lat=data.coord.lat;
              var long=data.coord.lon;
              var udata=data.name;
              var latlng = L.latLng(lat, long);    
              map.panTo([lat,long],13);
              var circle = L.circle([lat, long], {
                color: 'red',
                fillColor: '#f03',
                fillOpacity: 0.5,
                radius: 1000
            }).addTo(map);
            var marker= L.marker(latlng).addTo(map)
              var popup = L.popup()
              .setLatLng(latlng)
              .setContent(udata)
              .openOn(map);
               console.log(data.name);
              
              });
          });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to clear the previous layer from the map instance. You can try creating a layer group and add the layer to/remove it from that ([DOCS](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#layergroup)):

```js
// Create a layer group
const layerGroup = L.layerGroup().addTo(map)

clickme.addEventListener("click",my=(e)=>{
          e.preventDefault();
          var city=search.value;
          fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&appid=ac3673a8887645fc3d0493904a348e03`)
          .then(response=> response.json())
          .then(data=>{
  
              // Clear the layer group
              layerGroup.clearLayers()
    
              var lat=data.coord.lat;
              var long=data.coord.lon;
              var udata=data.name;
              var latlng = L.latLng(lat, long);    
              map.panTo([lat,long],13);
              var circle = L.circle([lat, long], {
                color: 'red',
                fillColor: '#f03',
                fillOpacity: 0.5,
                radius: 1000
            }).addTo(layerGroup); // Add to layerGroup instead of map

            // Add marker to layerGroup instead of map
            var marker= L.marker(latlng).addTo(layerGroup)
              var popup = L.popup()
              .setLatLng(latlng)
              .setContent(udata)
              .openOn(map);
               console.log(data.name);
              
              });
          });
```

Comment: Thanks brother! second way works correctly. first one also works but it removes map I mean it show plain map with no structure of map but shows marker on search location. i was confused form 5 days thanks a lot again!

Comment: No problem! I've removed the map.removeLayers() example since it didn't work properly. Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

You should store the marker in a variable like:

`var marker = L.marker(latlng).addTo(map)`
and then you will be able to move the marker with:
`marker.setLatLng(latlng);`

Comment: not working sorry!